# Dragons and Magicules

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

Do dragons constantly create magicules, or do they just absorb them from the atmosphere?  If they do, why do they release them from their body, or is it that they can not stop it?

Answer (score 2):

**(Spoilers ahead from the light novel published recently)**

*I refer to rimuru as a he due to its gender being male in the previous life

---

All monsters in the realm exude energy from their body. All monsters are created based on the density of magicules. This was why the Jura Forest had a high density of monsters due to the release of Veldora's magicules over the centuries. The only difference between a dragon's release and a normal slime's release is the amount of magicules that is produced.

From Volume 7 of the light novel,

> A lot of residents were practically brimming with magicules; the air was pretty dense with them by now, which was exactly how you got mystic beasts—they’d spontaneously manifest from pools of the stuff, and the more that were created, the more likely at least one would be harmful to us.

In the light novel published, there are multiple instances where this is mentioned

> Rimuru releases a mysterious aura when he first meets the goblins which leads them to believe he is a very strong monster. Rimuru then learns to control his aura by trapping inside his stomach.

> Rimuru forces Veldora to contain his own magicule release in order to prevent a catastrophe wrecking Tempest City due to the excessive release of magicules.

Their aura that they release is the release of magicules and the stronger the being, the more magicules they release.

In a later part of the novel, Rimuru also talks about the magicule density near Tempest being high to the point where it could start to discomfort other merchants who came for business, which leads to their breakthroughs in magicule research and development.

From Volume 7 of the light novel,

> [..] unnaturally full of magicules. We were all projecting pretty heavy auras even when we tried to hold them back.

The magicules are like oxygen to the monsters, it helps them survive, yet just like oxygen a very large amount or very little can cause damage to their metabolic rates.

> This feature is exploited by the Western Holy Church during their massacre of the monsters and Hinata during her first fight with Rimuru.

All in all, just like we breathe oxygen in and release some oxygen while exhaling, the monsters *breathe* magicules.

Comment: Hi, this looks like a solid answer, and it'd be better if you could also mention the specific volume/chapter of the light novel as a reference. Thanks!

Comment: @AkiTanaka, do I need to add citations for each reference that I make? since they come from memory and I would have to look and find out if that's the case.

Comment: The current revision is okay. It's just that "*the light novel published recently*" may confuse readers (when is "recently"? which one was published?), considering that [the current volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_That_Time_I_Got_Reincarnated_as_a_Slime_volumes) for the light novel is #18 for the Japanese version and #10 (soon #11) for the English version.